# Match javascript class with html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html

```
<a class="idents" href="#"></a>
<a class="idents" href="#"></a>
<a class="idents" href="#"></a>
```

and this javascript

```
function show(selected) {
    $('a[class|="idents"]').each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).attr("id") == selected) {
            $(this).show(600);
        }
        else {
            $(this).hide(600);
        }
    });
}
```

I will like to remove the repeating a class from the html put all anchors into a div

Like this

```
<div class="idents">
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

But I am completely javascript newbie and don't how to change the javascript to "match" the change in the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like you would select with css.

```
$('.idents a').each(function(index) {  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following selector:

```
$("div.idents a").each(...);
```

This will iterate through all `<a>` within your `<div>`.

Comment: If it's perfect, be nice and vote it up or select it as the chosen answer.

Comment: I can only select it in 4 minutes time, I have waiting for  5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

```
function show(selected) {
  $('div.idents a').each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).attr("id") == selected) {
      $(this).show(600);
    } else {
      $(this).hide(600);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="ident">
     <a class="idents" href="#"></a>
             <a class="idents" href="#"></a>
             <a class="idents" href="#"></a>
           </div>


function show(selected) {
$('.ident a[class|="idents"]').each(function(index) {
if ($(this).attr("id") == selected) {
$(this).show(600);
}
else {
$(this).hide(600);
}
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Javascript.

The quoted thing that is on the inside of `$(    )` is a CSS selector. Check out any of the [many CSS selector tutorials](http://www.google.com/?q=css+selector+tutorial) on the internet to get an introduction on the topic.

To answer your question directly, you want `$('div.idents a')`.

Answer (score 0):

The line in your code that has this:

```
`$('a[class|="idents"]').each(function(index) {`
```

replace the `a` with `div`

```
$('div[class|="idents"] a').each(function(index) {
```